# How to Normalise features for small datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, preprocessing

I am working with a small dataset ( N  = 50 ).
I would like to normalise  my input features. 
I am facing the following issues:

1. Because of the small size of the dataset the range of training input features would differ from the range of testing input features.
2. The input features do not have a theoretical upper bound.

Can you suggest normalisation techniques suitable for this task? Any paper suggestions would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) on your train set, which will normalize your features inside **[0, 1]**. The same scaler can transform the test set and if there are values greater than the ones found in the train set, the scaler handles that by returning values greater than 1. Essentially, your test set will be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

You should normalise your dataset after the split. You could try out a standard scaling as in this way you avoid taking into account the minimum and maximum value.
The fact that you have 2 different ranges in train and test is not positive at all. In this case you can do some resampling such as SMOTE.
Let me know

Comment: Normalizing before splitting is a bad practice, because you incorporate knowledge from the test set into your preprocessing